# Is the group Z2 x Z9 cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

So I am doing a project and was given the group Z2 x Z9 and was told it was a noncyclic group. However, when finding the subgroups (1,1), (1,2), (1,4), (1,7), and (1,8) all generate the group. Am I doing it wrong or is the group actually cyclic?

Comment: A further question: do you notice anything interesting about those four elements that generate the whole group? (HINT: what does $1$ do in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$? What do $1, 2, 4, 7, 8$ all do in $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$?)

Answer (score 6):

It is indeed a cyclic group. In general, $\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n_2\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic if and only if $n_1$ and $n_2$ are relatively prime - this is a good exercise. In particular, if $n_1$ and $n_2$ are relatively prime, then $$\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n_2\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/n_1n_2\mathbb{Z}.$$ And a similar statement is true for products of finitely many cyclic groups.

Comment: Even more generally, $G_1\times G_2$ is a cyclic group if and only if either one is cyclic and the other is trivial, or both are finite cyclic of coprime orders (and by induction, the same is true for other finite products).